# REST with nested JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a JSON Object

```
{
 "firstname": "foo",
 "account":
 {
   "city": "bar"
 }
}
```

which I want serialize in a REST backend:

```
@POST
public Response create(Employee e)
```

Classes:

```
public class Employee {
  public String firstname; 
  private Address address;
}

public class Address {
  public String city; 
}
```

Unforutanetly, I always receive a `400` status code. But if I do

```
public Response create(Object o)
```

everything works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON does not correspond (map) to your POJO types. In the JSON, you have `account`, but in your Java type you have `address`.